# Python/Django - Value is reverting back after for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to pass the URL's of a list of photos to the template.  I'm concatenating my `MEDIA_URL` to every photo name.

When `print(a)` is run, I can see in the console that the concatenation was successfully added.  The result is something like `media/photo.jpg`.  However by the time the loop finishes, the result reverts back to the original `photo.jpg` as if no concatenation happened.  `print(photos)` shows a list of photos with no changes.

Why?

```
def get_property_data(request):
    property_id = request.GET.get('id')
    photos = ListingPhoto.objects.values_list('photo', flat=True).filter(listing__id=property_id)
    for a in photos:
        a = settings.MEDIA_URL + a
        print(a)
    print(photos)

    return JsonResponse({'property': list(photos)})
```

Comment: In `for a in photos`, `a` is copy of the elements inside `photos`. Therefore modifying `a` doesn't modify the values in the iterable `photos`. Maybe you want: `for i in range(len(photos)): photos[i] += settings.MEDIA_URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputting photos which is unchanged.  Also you are looping through on **a** and changing the value, over and over again.

Try something like this instead

```
b = []
for a in photos:
        b.append(settings.MEDIA_URL + a)
        print(a)
print(b) # b is an array of url strings
```